# Get forwarded type from the template type and not the argument

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, perfect-forwarding, trailing-return-type

Consider the following function:

```
template <class T>
constexpr /* something */ f(T&& x) {
    // do something
}
```

and let's say that I want to do sfinae based on the type of a forwarded argument passed to a function called `myfunction`. One way to achieve this is:

```
template <class T>
constexpr auto f(T&& x) -> decltype(myfunction(std::forward<T>(x))) {
    // do something
}
```

instead of doing this, is there a way to do it at the template level:

```
// This code won't compile
template <class T, class R = decltype(myfunction(std::forward<T>(x)))>
constexpr R f(T&& x) {
    // do something
}
```

except that I don't have access to `x` yet so this code won't compile. Is there a way to achieve this only based on `T` (possibly using `std::declval`)?

Note: this is not an X/Y problem, it's just an example to illustrate where this situation happen: I don't know how to do SFINAE with forwarding without accessing the variable because for me the behavior of `std::forward` is still a little mysterious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `std::declval` is indeed the key:

```
template <class T, class R = decltype(myfunction(std::declval<T>()))>
constexpr R f(T&& x) {
    // do something
}
```

This will either SFINAE out or `R` will be the return type of whichever overload of `myfunction` is chosen.

Your question makes it appear to me that you need a refresher on how reference-collapsing works; I suggest reading up in that area ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582313/636019) seems like a good starting point).

Comment: I would mention that this is a poor approach, for one can easily break it by passing a second parameter.

Comment: @skypjack : Right, thus avoiding any SFINAE taking place.

Comment: Yeah, by saying _break it_ I meant that. Sorry if it wasn't clear. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`std::forward()` has nothing to do with this question. Nor does `constexpr`. So let's start out with the super basic, a function that just returns its argument by value:

```
template <class T>
auto f(T x) -> decltype(x);
```

Sure, we could just use `T`, but that's too easy. Now the question, how do we lift that into a template parameter while still maintaining SFINAE (granted there's obviously no possible substitution failure here, but bear with me):

```
template <class T, class R = decltype(x)>
R f(T x);
```

So that doesn't work because there's no `x` yet (or worse, there's some unrelated `x` somewhere else that name lookup finds). We can use the argument names in a trailing-return-type because they're in scope, but we cannot use them as part of expression-SFINAE in default template arguments because they're not yet in scope.

But because these are template parameters, we don't care about their *values*. We just care about their *types*. This isn't an evaluated expression. So I don't need `x`, I need something that has the same type as `x`. A first go might be:

```
template <class T, class R = decltype(T{})>
R f(T x);
```

This works... as long as `T` is default-constructible. But I'm writing a template, I don't want to be making assumptions on types that I don't need to be making. So instead, I can do something like:

```
template <class T> T make(); // never defined

template <class T, class R = decltype(make<T>())>
R f(T x);
```

And now we have our arbitrary expression of type `T`, that we can use in `decltype`, in a default template argument. Although, we're *still* a little limited with `make()` - there are types that you can't return by value from a functon (e.g. arrays), so it turns out to be more useful to add references. And we need a less-likely-to-collide name than `make`:

```
template <class T>
add_rvalue_reference<T> declval();

template <class T, class R = decltype(declval<T>())>
R f(T x);
```

This is precisely the point of `std::declval<T>` - to give you an expression of type `T` in an unevaluated context.

---

Back to your original problem. We use the same thought process of how to get from `decltype(x)` to `decltype(declval<T>())`, but just apply it to a different expression. Instead of `x`, we have `myfunction(std::forward<T>(x))`. Which is to say, we're invoking `myfunction` with the same type as our argument:

```
template <class T, class R = decltype(myfunction(std::declval<T&&>()))>
R f(T&& x);
```

But due to reference collapsing rules, `std::declval<T&&>` is actually the same function as `std::declval<T>`, so we can just write:

```
template <class T, class R = decltype(myfunction(std::declval<T>()))>
R f(T&& x);
```